# Oracle regexp_like failing on FLOAT from view

Tags: oracle, view, regexp-like

I'm trying to use regexp_like to find and remove overly-precise floating point numbers.

```
select c from t order by c asc;
```

returns many results like this: 0.0000000012345678

Using regexp_like I can get results for two decimal places (0.25):

```
select * from t where REGEXP_LIKE(c,'^\d+\.\d{2}');
```

However, when I try anything more than two places, I get no results:

```
select * from t where REGEXP_LIKE(c,'^\d+\.\d{3}');
...
select * from t where REGEXP_LIKE(c,'^\d+\.\d{10}');
```

The only add'l info is that I'm selecting against a view of a second view and the column I'm searching (c, above) is designated as a FLOAT.

Comment: Do you have values with exactly 3 or exactly 10 digts after the decimal point? If they're floats (numbers) why are you trying to filter them using string functions?

Comment: Are you sure you're actually even matching 0.25? I can see 1.25 working, but the implicit `to_char(c)` you're doing won't have a zero before the decimal point?

Comment: Yes, there are entries with 1-15 decimal places. I think your trunc() will work. Trying it now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat them as numbers. You can [truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TRUNC-number.html) the value to a fixed number of decimal places:

> The `TRUNC` (number) function returns *n1* truncated to *n2* decimal places.

and then see if it matches. For example, to find any values with more than 2 significant digits after the decimal point:

```
 select * from t where c != trunc(c, 2);
```

or to find those with more than 10 significant digits:

```
 select * from t where c != trunc(c, 10);
```

I've used `!=` rather than `>` in case you have negative values.

You can also use that as a filter in a delete/update, or as the `set` part of an update if you want to reduce the precision - though in that case you might want to use `round()` instead fo `trunc()`.

---

When you use `regexp_like` you're doing an implicit conversion of your float value to a string, and as [the docs for `to_char()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-number.html) note:

> If you omit *fmt*, then *n* is converted to a `VARCHAR2` value exactly long enough to hold its significant digits.

which means that 0.25 becomes the string `'.25'`, with no leading zero; which doesn't match even your first pattern.

You can allow for that leading zero not being there by using `*` instead of `+`, e.g. to find values with at least 10 significant digits after the decimal point:

```
select * from t where REGEXP_LIKE(c,'^\d*\.\d{10}');
```

or with *exactly* 10:

```
select * from t where REGEXP_LIKE(c,'^\d*\.\d{10}$');
```

etc.; but it seems simpler to treat them just as numbers rather than as strings.